# How to get ordered values from an unordered NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios4

I am trying to fetch and display contents from table.Currently i am running a query and store those id, and category name using `NSMutableDictionary` which works fine.

But I face one issue when i store the contents into NSMutableDictionary the order gets changed.When searching for this issue , it seems that this is the default behavior of the NSMutableDictionary.

I am not sure and how to use and what use to store the key pair value.

Please advice me that how can i overcome this problem

Thanks for stopping by...

```
//====================================================================
- ( NSMutableDictionary * ) getDataToDisplayTierOne:(NSString*)dbPath{
//====================================================================

    NSMutableDictionary *aTierOneTemplateData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        const char *sql_query_stmt = "select * from main_categories";

        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql_query_stmt, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {           
            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {   
                NSString *aValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                    (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

                NSString *aId = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];


                [aTierOneTemplateData setObject:aId forKey:aValue];

                [aValue release];
                [aId release];
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);    
    }   
    sqlite3_close(database); 

    return aTierOneTemplateData;

}
```

> Note : - I understand the limitations on using the nsmutabledictionery
>   so i expecting your advice to that how can i overcome / fetch id,
>   value in other way.please suggest

Updated

For example

Apple 1
Orange 2
Papaya 3

Actually i want that list to display it on my uitableview

Apple
Orange
Papaya

When tapping on each cell , i want to have its id value
for instance , i tap on Orange , now i want to have that id value as 2

Can you please tell me how to iterate over array of dictionery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSMutableDictionary`.

Change the declaration

```
NSMutableDictionary *aTierOneTemplateData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

to

```
NSMutableArray *aTierOneTemplateList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

And add the abjects to the array,

```
[aTierOneTemplateList addObject:aId];
```

And return the NSMutableArray,

```
return aTierOneTemplateList;
```

**Edit:**

If you modify the while loop as follows, you will get array of `NSDictionary`s with the same order.

```
NSString *aValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                    (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

NSString *aId = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:aValue,@"value",aId,@"key", nil];
[aTierOneTemplateList addObject:dict];
[dict release];
[aValue release];
[aId release];
```

**Edit2:**

Consider now in your tableviewcontroller, you have array of `NSDictionary`s (say `aTierOneTemplateList`).

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method,

```
NSDictionary *dict = [aTierOneTemplateList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *key = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];
NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:@"value"];
```

Similarly in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.By using your code , i can only get the ids not the ids and its values..so how i can i handle this...pls let me know

Comment: Hi Adhira : please see my updated question ( Can you please show me that how to iterate over array of nsmutabledictionery )

Answer (score 1):

Neither NSDictionary nor NSSet are ordered collections. If you want ordering, use NSArray. If you want to impose ordering, add objects to unordered collections that have their own index attribute.

Comment: pls find my updated question with code. i understand the limitations on using the nsdictionery.pls let me know your help